# Slidingdrawer no return point

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm using a SlidingDrawer for a lock screen. My problem is the handler closed when I drag to the middle of the slidindrawer. I want it only keep closed when I drag to be closed. In all other cases the handler must be animate to open. I'm trying to handler:

```
public void onScrollEnded() {
    if (!slide.isOpened())
        slide.open();
}
```

It opens but after this, it continues with de usual movement. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to

```
setOnDrawerScrollListener(SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerScrollListener onDrawerScrollListener)
```

[API Reference for SlidingDrawer.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Comment: Yes, onScrollEnded is a method of this listener. The problem is i want the effect of a lock screen: if the handler doesn't completely closed return to open. I'm trying with offset but i doesn't understand how to use them to get the effect of returning always to the open position.

Comment: Mmmm I understand now.. Are you sure that the SlidingDrawer is the best solution?
Maybe you have to overwrite the method that manage your closure or building a new view :)

Comment: Thanks Simone, but i'm near to get i'm looking for. I only have to understand how to convine offsets and width of the handler to do it. I thanks any ideas in this way.